# Replacing Day/Month format with Year on a Squarespace Template

Tags: javascript, templates, squarespace

I'm using Squarespace's Foundry template and it displays dates in a "Mon Day" format. I'd like instead to display the year (and only the year) of publication. A member of this community helped someone else change the way the months displayed in the same template ([Change date format on a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818671/change-date-format-on-a-template)); I'm wondering if someone might be able to help me with this other, similar challenge, too.

If you're able to help me with this, would you also be able to let me know where in the template to inject the Javascript? (I actually have not had success getting the month-display code to work even as a test -- I tried it to see if I could play with it and change it myself, but it didn't work, and I wonder whether I'm inserting it in the wrong place?).

Thank you so much, regardless,
Maggie

Answer (score 0):

The following Javascript, inserted via [site code injection](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815908-Using-Code-Injection#toc-step-1---open-code-injection), ought to do the trick:

> In the **Home Menu**, click **Settings**, click **Advanced**, and then click **Code Injection**.

Use the "Footer" injection area.

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var dates = document.getElementsByClassName("dt-published date-highlight");
        var date;
        var i,I;

        // Loop through all dates, replacing inner HTML with date from 'datetime' attribute.
        for (i=0, I=dates.length; i<I; i++) {
            date = dates[i];
            date.innerHTML = date.getAttribute("datetime").split("-")[0];
        }
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Super-satisfying to read the above, and really appreciate your help moving this problem in the right direction. Now -- I feel like a crazyperson but I've gone into Home > Settings > Advanced > Code Injection and pasted exactly the above into the field that says "HEADER
/ Enter code that will be injected into the 'head' tag on every page of your site" ...and saved... and then nothing has happened. Am I pasting into the wrong field? What bizarre user error is this? LMK if you have suggestions pls, and thanks.

Comment: p.s. I know that this is not, uhhh, a Squarespace Code Injection help forum. ;-) So if you don't feel like dealing with this, I totally understand -- and I really appreciate the help to begin with!

Comment: I should have clarified: use the "Footer" code injection area.